# Bounding $H(x)=x\log \frac{x}{p} + (1-x)\log\frac{1-x}{1-p} $

Tags: real-analysis, probability, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to demonstrate that $H(p+x)\geq 2x^2$, where $H(x)=x\log \frac{x}{p} + (1-x)\log\frac{1-x}{1-p} $ and $p,x\in (0,1)$, $p<p+x<1$. Any hint? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: By any chance, do you know anything about entropy and such stuff?

Comment: I think this function is named like this, but nothing more...